# why Facebook SDK 5 autoload.php do not let loading my other classes with __autoload

Tags: php, facebook

I'm new in Facebook SDK and I'm trying to load my header and footer (class.Header.incand class.Footer.inc are in the same folder as index page) PHP classes with the following code 
gives this error

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Footer' not found C:\wamp64\www\...
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/master/login-on-website-get-basic-info.php

```
<html>
  <head>        
    ...
<?php
   function __autoload($class_name)
   {
    include 'class.' . $class_name . '.inc';
   }
    <!-- Header -->
        $header = new Header();
        echo $header->display(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
        ?>

...
    <?php
      session_start();
      require_once '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
      $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([   
      .....
      echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}


 .... html ....
    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php 
    $footer = new Footer();
    echo $footer->display();
    ?>
```

I don't have an explication of why the function __autoload($class_name) isn't loading up the footer class

Comment: FYI: `__autoload` is **deprecated** as of PHP 7.2.0. You should use [`sql_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead.

Comment: Does it find the Header class?

Comment: yes it does, the header HTML code works fine, however the coder code shows up that error

Comment: @Bytewave I've tried         function my_autoload ($pClassName) {
            include("class." . $pClassName . ".inc");
        }
        spl_autoload_register("my_autoload");

Comment: @Bytewave I've tried `spl_autoload_register()` fails in the included Facebook SDK code, I've used this, it works but not practical with any classes  `<?php 
  require 'class.Footer.inc';
  require 'class.Header.inc';
        ?> 
  ....

   <!-- Header -->
   <?php 
   $header = new Header();
   
   echo $header->display(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
   ?>`